# Accessing Application Context in Core Java module inside for JUnit test in Android app

Tags: android, junit4

I have an Android App, which contains multiple java modules, means non-android modules.
One module is core module which has no dependency on Android App module. But it takes Application Context at runtime.

I need to create a JUnit test case in this core module, that requires Android Application Context. I can do this by adding dependency of the Android Application module in core module in IntelliJ Idea by going to Project Settings.

But just for a JUnit test, I don't want to place dependency. Is there any way to mock this Application Context?

Please, let me know if anybody needs more clarification.

Comment: How can a class in pure java module work with Context when Context is not in the classpath?

Comment: @Eugen See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock context like below using `Mockito` and use that :

```
private Context context;

context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
```

Comment: Yes, it works.+1 for that.  But why can't we call getAssets() on this object.  I referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407178/mocking-android-assetmanager but no avail.

Comment: What about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others

Comment: @Meenal : I get error. Cannot mock/spy class android.content.res.AssetManager
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types

Comment: @Eugen: doesn't  fulfill requirement

Comment: @AnishMittal I suggest you to use Robolectric for this, if it suits your requirement..as it provides Shadow Classes for all..so you don't have to mock..

Comment: @Meenal: I am using Android API 16 in IntelliJ Idea. Robolectric 1.2.jar & robolectric- 1.2-8-jar-with-dependencies.jar throwing  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/View". Even, I am not using any view.